# How to configure Aws Amplify for a AppSync subscription Websocket endpoint?

Tags: typescript, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

How do I specify a websocket endpoint using `Amplify.configure(awsConfig)` The docs only demonstrate how to do a singular http endpoint using the `aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint`

[AWS Amplify.configure docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/client-configuration/configuring-amplify-categories/q/platform/js#graphql-api-aws-appsync).

I have separate appsync urls one is a "realtime" websocket url.

```
REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT_HTTP
REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT_WS
```

I am trying to connect to AppSync with the AWS Amplify SDK using the [Amplify graphql subscriptions](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/subscribe-data/q/platform/js#using-amplify-graphql-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that `aws-amplify` will automatically configure the websocket endpoint based on the http endpoint when you use `Amplify.configure(awsConfig)`. Did not see this mentioned any where and is a bit magical.

Answer (score 0):

It will autogenerate subscription .. Also If you are using GraphQl schema then you can do like this `@model(queries: { get: "getUser", list: "listUsers" }, subscriptions: null)`